# ag-grid does not work properly with angular 1.x

Tags: datatable, webpack, ag-grid, angular1.6

I am trying to use ag-grid for one of my project work and was trying to configure it with webpack & Angular 1.6

i have configured it as follow

## Module

```
var agGrid = require('ag-grid');
agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);

module.exports = angular.module('transModule', ['agGrid'])
.component('transComponent', transComponent)
.name;
```

## Controller

```
  var columnDefs = [
        {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
        {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
        {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
    ];

    var rowData = [
        {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
        {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
        {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
    ];

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowData: rowData
    };
```

## html

```
<div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 100%;"></div>
```

but when i use i, it displays as follow
[image: table view]

then i tried adding the stylesheets as follow

require('ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css');
   require('ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css');

yet again it the table want render properly and it will show as follow

[image]

is there anything um missing?? I would much appreciate if you could give me some headsup??

Comment: Having the same issue, did you find out why?

Comment: @Duane sorry i couldn't find a viable solution for this, I am now using Angular UI-Grid as an alternative

Comment: I got it to work by applying this, but using ag-grid instead of Font Awesome. https://charlouze.github.io/ionic/2017/05/31/Ionic-3-and-Font-Awesome.html

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in ag-grid's `package.json` it was referenced `main.js` as entry point, and I actually found the whole `lib` folder content loaded in the Source tab of Chrome DevTools.

This was due to the way I was requiring ag-grid:

```
var agGrid = require('ag-grid');
// get ag-Grid to create an Angular module and register the ag-Grid directive
agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);

var myApp = 'myApp';
module.exports = myApp;

angular
  .module(myApp, [
    'agGrid'
  ])
```

Even if the "get-started" docs don't list a Webpack based solution, they do say to include the `dist/ag-grid.js` file or  one of the minified/noStyle versions, **so I changed the first line like this:**

```
var agGrid = require('ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js');
```